# Single onChange function for multiple input fields is not working: ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**Code:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Button, Input, Row, Col, Label } from 'reactstrap';

export default class  Settings extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { 
            tallyPort: '', companyYear: '', interval: '', timeRange: '', 
            databasePort: '', databaseUserName: '', databasePassword: '' 
        };  
    }

    handleChange = (stateName, e) => {
        this.setState({ stateName: e.target.value });
    }

    handleSave = () => {
        console.log(this.state)
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div className="dashboard" >
                <Input name="tallyPort" onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, 'tallyPort')}  />
                <Input name="companyYear" onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, 'companyYear')} />
                <Input name="interval" onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, 'companyYear')} />
                <Input name="timeRange" onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, 'companyYear')} />
                <Input name="databasePort" onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, 'companyYear')} />
                <Input name="databaseUserName" onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, 'companyYear')} />
                <Input name="databasePassword" onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, 'companyYear')} />

                <Button style={{ width: '200px', marginLeft: '720px'}} onClick={this.handleSave.bind(this)} color="primary">Save</Button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Main problem with `this.setState` function, I'm not understand why it is not working.
I'm trying to set each state value on `"onChange"` of input field, `"setState"` is not working properly, when i'm console all states after given values, it returns blank values, any one help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Basic Idea:**

You need to use [**Computed property name**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) concept, to use the expressions for object property names. For that you have to put the expression inside `[]`.

---

**Solution:**

You are passing the `state` variable name in `onChange` function, so you need to use `[]` because it will be a variable that will hold some `state` variable name, then only it will update that `state` variable.

If you don't use `[]` then, `stateName` will be treated as a **key (string)**, it will create a new `state` variable with name `stateName` and put the value in that.

Write it like this:

```
handleChange(stateName, e) {
    this.setState({ [stateName]: e.target.value });
}
```

Check this:

```js
let obj = {b: 5};

let a = 'b';

obj = {...obj, a: 20}; //similar to setState

obj = {...obj, [a]: 1};

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above the Computed property name is the key to this solution. This solution worked well for me.

```
constructor() {
  super(props);
  this.state = {tallyPort: '', companyYear: '', interval: '', timeRange: '', 
            databasePort: '', databaseUserName: '', databasePassword: ''};
  this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
}

// assigning the name and value is the main objective of this solution.
handleChange = (e) => {
  this.setState({
     [e.target.name]: e.target.value
  })
}

render() {
    return(
        <div className="dashboard" >
            <Input name="tallyPort" onChange={this.handleChange}  />
            <Input name="companyYear" onChange={this.handleChange} />
            <Input name="interval" onChange={this.handleChange} />
            <Input name="timeRange" onChange={this.handleChange} />
            <Input name="databasePort" onChange={this.handleChange} />
            <Input name="databaseUserName" onChange={this.handleChange} />
            <Input name="databasePassword" onChange={this.handleChange} />

            <Button style={{ width: '200px', marginLeft: '720px'}} onClick={this.handleSave.bind(this)} color="primary">Save</Button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

I hope this solution helps. Thanks.